# C# Сканирование всех файлов в папке и выполняя задание

Tags: c#, winforms, for, closedxml

Нужно как то составить код, чтобы **Программа по указанному пути выбирала файлы (в данном случае все файлы будут XlsX и выполняла действия, которые написаны в кнопках**

Пример кода (как я его вижу):

```
    //Выбор нужной папки
    OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
    opf.ShowDialog();
    // РАБОЧАЯ ЧАСТЬ КОДА (существующая)
    using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(opf.FileName))  //using ClosedXML
    {
    IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet("Лист1");
    //создание таблицы
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    bool firstRow = true;
foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells()) //добавляем колонки в таблице
{
dt.Columns.Add(cell.WorksheetColumn().ColumnLetter());
}
    }
    this.dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = workSheet.Cell("B" + 5).Value;

    //Код который нужно дополнительно сделать (по мимо сканирования папки)
    Button1.click(); //выполнение действия написанные в кнопки
    Button2.click();
```

*Если не понятно что-то, то напишите в комментарии, я отвечу и постараюсь перефразировать свои слова*

Comment: `C# Сканирование всех файлов в папке и выполняя задание` - как вы пытались сами это решить и какие возникли проблемы?

Comment: @tym32167 у меня даже в голове на самом деле не укладывается как это сделать. Очень давно видел как кто-то так делал (но я потерял ссылку), возможно наверное (проще) создать textbox (для написания пути к файлам)и сделать цикл через for. Но вопрос в том, что я не знаю как сделать нумерацию файлов (можно наверное переименовать файлы типа (1.xlsx,2xlsx) и через цикл прогонять каждый файл примерно так:
`for (int i = 1; i < [number file] ; i ++)
{
//Действия
}`

Comment: Для выбора пути можно использовать `FolderBrowserDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывай не кнопку, а методы.
Создай отдельный класс(например ActionWrite.cs), в него запихни метод(ы), которые тебе нужно.
И потом вызывай уже методы, а не кнопки.

Пример:

```
class ActionWrite{

public void WriteOneWord()
{
//любые действия
}
}
```

А потом уже вызывай:

```
ActionWrite write = new ActionWrite();
write.WriteOneWord();
```

Comment: Окей, спасибо про кнопки, а можешь что-то сказать про for (чтоб он каждый файл в папке проводил через класс)?

Comment: Алгоритм простой, т.к щас VS под рукой нет, код приложить вот так на ходу не смогу :)

У компонента OpenFileDialog есть свойство MultiSelect(посмотри).
Значит по сути должно получиться так:
OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog()

Как только через окно ты выделил нужные тебе файлы.

Можно пройтись так
for (int i = 0; i < opf.count; i++)
{
тут все твои действия
}
[ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect?view=netframework-4.7)